# docker: автоматическое присваивание доменного имени контейнеру

Tags: docker, ip, dns, домен

Я запускаю несколько контейнеров docker и хочу, чтобы к каждому контейнеру можно было обратиться не по IP, а по доменному имени, например: [http://имя_контейнера.local.dev](http://%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.local.dev)

Можно прописать их руками в `/etc/hosts`, но я хочу, чтобы это происходило автоматически.

Я нашел [crosbymichael/skydock](https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydock), специально предназначенный для этой цели, но там в самом начале написано:

> Docker supports DNS based service discovery now. You should use the Docker implementation instead of this project.

Я так понимаю, docker уже поддерживает это из коробки, но не понимаю, как это настраивается.

Как же сделать, чтобы доменные имена для контейнеров автоматически регистрировались на моем компьютере? Умеет докер это делать или все-таки нужно использовать вспомогательные утилиты?

Comment: [здесь](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27790) предлагается несколько решений, но, конечно, docker не подразумевает такой работы.

Comment: @etki я не понимаю, почему то, что я хочу - это что-то такое странное, для чего нет готового удобного решения. Решения по ссылке я посмотрел - сыровато, все нужно дорабатывать. Что в моей концепции не так и как правильно? Я просто хочу запускать несколько проектов в docker и обращаться к ним по ссылке в браузере, не парясь на тему, какой IP получил запущенный контейнер в этот раз.